# Domino Server Controller is not running on the host, or not listening to port 2050

Tags: lotus-domino, domino-appdev-pack

I am following the App Dev Pack to configure the domino server.
After I　tried to setup ldap configuration, then the following error message occured.

The server.kyr is kyring file using the make_certs.cmd and make_keying.cmd from the App Dev Pack.

Here is the error message when running.

```
[1760:0005-17A8] 2022/07/13 下午 12:11:04  CertStore: LDAP: Cannot find TLS Credential for [serv.org.com.kyr] (RSA: 1, ECDSA: 1) : Entry not found in index
[1760:0002-17A8] 2022/07/13 下午 12:11:05  LDAP Server: Started
[07FC:0002-15B0] 2022/07/13 下午 12:11:07  JVM: Java Virtual Machine initialized.
[07FC:0002-15B0] 2022/07/13 下午 12:11:07  HTTP Server: Java Virtual Machine loaded
[0518:0002-16B0] 2022/07/13 下午 12:11:07  JVM: Java Virtual Machine initialized.
[0518:0002-16B0] 2022/07/13 下午 12:11:07.47 PROTON> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3002, SSL-ENABLED
[07FC:0002-15B0] 2022/07/13 下午 12:11:07.47 CSRF Init: iNotes_WA_Security_ReturnUrlCheck> c_CSRFReturnUrlCheck: 1

[0518:0002-16B0] 2022/07/13 下午 12:11:07.47 PROTON> Server initialized
[0518:0002-16B0] 2022/07/13 下午 12:11:07.47 PROTON> Server allows Anonymous access only.
[0518:0005-0A4C] 2022/07/13 下午 12:11:08.42 PROTON> SessionCache::prune: enter
[0518:0005-0A4C] 2022/07/13 下午 12:11:08.44 PROTON> SessionCache::prune: exit
[0518:0005-0A4C] 2022/07/13 下午 12:11:24.16 PROTON> SessionCache::prune: enter
[0518:0005-0A4C] 2022/07/13 下午 12:11:29.27 PROTON> SessionCache::prune: exit
[07FC:0002-15B0] 2022/07/13 下午 12:11:30  XSP Command Manager initialized
[07FC:0002-15B0] 2022/07/13 下午 12:11:30  HTTP Server: Error - Unable to Bind serv.org.com, port 80, port in use or Bind To Host configuration specifies a duplicate IP address/host
[07FC:0002-15B0] 2022/07/13 下午 12:11:31  XSP Command Manager terminated
[07FC:0002-15B0] 2022/07/13 下午 12:11:32  HTTP Server: Shutdown
[0518:0005-0A4C] 2022/07/13 下午 12:11:44.74 PROTON> SessionCache::prune: enter
[0518:0005-0A4C] 2022/07/13 下午 12:11:44.74 PROTON> SessionCache::prune: exit

[0518:0005-0A4C] 2022/07/13 下午 12:12:15.16 PROTON> SessionCache::prune: enter
[0518:0005-0A4C] 2022/07/13 下午 12:12:15.16 PROTON> SessionCache::prune: exit
[06A8:0002-07E0] 2022/07/13 下午 12:12:29  AMgr: Error executing agent 'DeleteExpiredDocs' in 'iam-store.nsf'. Agent signer 'Domino Template Development/Domino': You are not authorized to perform that operation
[0518:0005-0A4C] 2022/07/13 下午 12:12:30.40 PROTON> SessionCache::prune:
```

[image: The error message]

Answer (score 2):

Your error does not have anything to do with your changes in setup.

When you start the domino server, then it first starts the so called "Server Controller". This server controller is an executable (scontroller.exe under Windows), that listens on port 2050 for any Java remote console to connect.

The controller is configured in "dcontroller.ini" in your data directory.

You can check, if the controller runs using netstat in a command line:

```
netstat -ano |findstr 2050
```

will give you the following result, if the controller is running:

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:2050       0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3836
```

or if it is configured to a specific IP address:

```
TCP    172.16.0.21:2050       0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3836
```

To connect to the server using the Domino Server Console, it uses a file called "dconsole.ini" in the same directory as dcontroller.ini.

The dconsole.ini has an entry to point to controller called "LocalHost". It should point to the same IP / Hostname, that the controller listens to:

```
LocalHost=172.16.0.21:2050
```

This is usually the second line in that file. If it is missing: Add it and restart console.

Your error typically occurs if a server has more than one IP address / network card.